# hCard: listing contact form as email property

Tags: email, microformats, hcard

Is it possible to include an email in the hCard micro-format by linking to an contact form, instead of directly listing the email-address?

I would prefer this because of spam concerns.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use the `url` property for this rather the `email` one since the thing you want to mark up is not really an email address (but a URL).